# printing float value to console precision problem_

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I have just noticed something weird in my code

I have created simple app to show you what I'm talking about

```
float Test1 = 112.12;
float Test2 = 0.12;

printf("Test1 %15f", Test1);
printf("Test1 %15f", Test1);
```

I have always thought that if I write Test1 = 112.12 it means it's equal 112.120000000

however I get 112.120003

and on the second example I get 0.11999 or 0.120000 it depends

Could someone explain me why is this happening and what happens if I try to divide these two numbers will they get converted to double (or any other more precise data type) so I can get higher precision or they will be used in their current form (float)

I have used VS 2010 to test this (if it matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two observations:

1. computers use base 2, not base 10
2. floating-point numbers are not precise

Because of the first point, there are some numbers that don't translate well from our system to the computer's system.  0.3 can't be 100% precisely represented *directly* in binary (that's not to say that computers can't represent it precisely, just that they can't with the commonly used system).

Because of the second point, it's always dangerous to use floating-point numbers for exact values.  I would recommend reading the Wikipedia article on floating point numbers -- it mentions accuracy problems.

Comment: yep, I agree but isn't it more logical it "rounds" numbers to lower value like 0.119999 not higher value then I entered like in first example

Comment: @user996937 -- there's no "rounding" going on -- you've just given it a number that it can't represent exactly, and that's the best it can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way computers store numbers. Check these two wikipedia articles

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format

Do not use `float` except you really have to. Use `double` instead.

Comment: There's no need to avoid floats religiously.  I've heard people say the exact opposite, in fact.  Use what works best for you and your requirements.

Comment: @MattFenwick have they given reasons? On normal not too ancient consumer-grade hardware, the only reason to prefer float when you have the choice that I'm aware of, is space if you have a _lot_ of them.